# How to edit the score ranges in highcharter-histogram tooltip

Tags: r, r-highcharter

I am using the highcharter package to make a histogram. I want to get rid of the default score range display -`(x, y]`- and replace it with something that reads: `score ranges: x to y`

```
library(highcharter)
apple <- c(0, 22, 5, 32, 34, 35, 56, 67, 42, 67, 12, 99, 46, 78, 43, 67, 33, 11)
hchart(apple, color = "#a40c19", breaks = 20) %>% 
  hc_yAxis(title = list(text = "Number of Apples")) %>% 
  hc_xAxis(title = list(text = "Score (0-100)")) %>%
  hc_tooltip(borderWidth = 1, sort = TRUE, crosshairs = TRUE,
             pointFormat = "Score Range: {point.x} to {point.x} <br> Number of Apples: {point.y}") %>%
  hc_legend(enabled = FALSE)
```

For example, in the picture below, I want to get rid of the heading `(30, 35]` and replace it with `Score Range: 30 to 35`. 
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you need to know what is the interval length of your histogram:

```
library(highcharter)
apple <- c(0, 22, 5, 32, 34, 35, 56, 67, 42, 67, 12, 99, 46, 78, 43, 67, 33, 11)

h <- hist(apple, breaks = 20)
d <- diff(h$breaks)[1]
d
> d
[1] 5
```

Now, you need to use `pointFormatter` instead of `pointFormat` because allow you to have more control in the output of the tooltip. `pointFormat` need a string template and `pointFormatter` need a javascript function.

You put the `delta` in that function to get the right limits in for every interval. Obviously you can do it more elegant but that's the idea.

```
hchart(h, color = "#a40c19", breaks = 20) %>% 
  hc_yAxis(title = list(text = "Number of Apples")) %>% 
  hc_xAxis(title = list(text = "Score (0-100)")) %>%
  hc_tooltip(borderWidth = 1, sort = TRUE, crosshairs = TRUE,
             headerFormat = "",
             pointFormatter = JS("function() {
return 'Score Range:'  + (this.x - 5/2) + ' to ' + (this.x + 5/2) + '<br> Number of Apples:' +  this.y;    
             }")) %>%
  hc_legend(enabled = FALSE)
```

[image]

Finally you use `headerFormat = ""` to remove the header.

Comment: Thanks, I will try it next Monday after Thanksgiving and let you know!